# save separate separate xml file base on orderid

Tags: c#, xml, xml-generation

Hi all currently i have saved all the xml file in one file . but i need to save in separate file. could you please help me on it.

current code :-

```
 System.Data.DataTable checkFile = new System.Data.DataTable();
                sql = "sql";
                DBCon clsDB = new DBCon(SAPCompanySettings.MSSQLConnectionString);
                clsDB.Execute(sql, ref checkFile);                
            var stringwriter = new StringWriter();
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
            {
                xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
                var groups = checkFile.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { DocNum = x.Field<int>("orderid"), Type = x.Field<string>("Type"), Status = x.Field<string>("Status"), productno = x.Field<string>("productno"), ProductDescription = x.Field<string>("ProductDescription"), uom = x.Field<string>("uom"), customer = x.Field<string>("customer"), remark = x.Field<string>("remark"), U_JobNumber = x.Field<string>("U_JobNumber"), U_SalesPerson = x.Field<string>("U_SalesPerson"), U_JobType = x.Field<string>("U_JobType"), PlannedQty = x.Field<decimal>("PlannedQty"), OriginNum = x.Field<int?>("OriginNum"), orderdate = x.Field<DateTime>("orderdate"), duedate = x.Field<DateTime>("duedate") });
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("productionorder");
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("orderid", group.Key.DocNum.ToString());
                    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("type", group.Key.Type);    
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("status", group.Key.Status);             
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("productno", group.Key.productno);                              xmlWriter.WriteElementString("ProductDescription", group.Key.ProductDescription);                       
                      xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PlannedQty",group.Key.PlannedQty.ToString());                                              
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("uom", group.Key.uom);
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("salesorder", group.Key.OriginNum.ToString());                                                          xmlWriter.WriteElementString("customer", group.Key.customer);                        
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Remarks", group.Key.remark);
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("date");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("orderdate", group.Key.orderdate.ToString());
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("duedate", group.Key.duedate.ToString());
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("jobdescription", group.Key.U_JobNumber);                 
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("salesperson", group.Key.U_SalesPerson);
                    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("jobtype", group.Key.U_JobType);
                    foreach (DataRow row in group)
                    {
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Components");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("itemno", row.Field<string>("itemno"));
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    var sql2 = "update IS_XML_generated='Y' from OWOR where DocNum=group.Key.DocNum";
                    clsDB.Execute(sql2);
                }
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            }
            var xml = stringwriter.ToString();
            XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
            docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
            docSave.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\DEMO PSL\DOXMLFILE", "Filename.xml"));
```

Current output:-

filename.xml:-both order is saved in same file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <productionorder orderid="1">
  ...................
  </productionorder>
  <productionorder orderid="2">
    ...............
  </productionorder>
</Root>
```

but expected output :-i need to save different different file
1.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <productionorder orderid="1">
    ..............
  </productionorder>
</Root>
```

2.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <productionorder orderid="2">
    ............
  </productionorder>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I swapped the using and the foreach loops.  I also modify filename so each filename is unique.

```
             System.Data.DataTable checkFile = new System.Data.DataTable();
                sql = "sql";
                DBCon clsDB = new DBCon(SAPCompanySettings.MSSQLConnectionString);
                clsDB.Execute(sql, ref checkFile);                

            var groups = checkFile.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { DocNum = x.Field<int>("orderid"), Type = x.Field<string>("Type"), Status = x.Field<string>("Status"), productno = x.Field<string>("productno"), ProductDescription = x.Field<string>("ProductDescription"), uom = x.Field<string>("uom"), customer = x.Field<string>("customer"), remark = x.Field<string>("remark"), U_JobNumber = x.Field<string>("U_JobNumber"), U_SalesPerson = x.Field<string>("U_SalesPerson"), U_JobType = x.Field<string>("U_JobType"), PlannedQty = x.Field<decimal>("PlannedQty"), OriginNum = x.Field<int?>("OriginNum"), orderdate = x.Field<DateTime>("orderdate"), duedate = x.Field<DateTime>("duedate") });
            int count = 1;
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                var stringwriter = new StringWriter();
                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
                {
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("productionorder");
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("orderid", group.Key.DocNum.ToString());
                    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("type", group.Key.Type);    
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("status", group.Key.Status);             
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("productno", group.Key.productno);                              xmlWriter.WriteElementString("ProductDescription", group.Key.ProductDescription);                       
                      xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PlannedQty",group.Key.PlannedQty.ToString());                                              
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("uom", group.Key.uom);
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("salesorder", group.Key.OriginNum.ToString());                                                          xmlWriter.WriteElementString("customer", group.Key.customer);                        
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Remarks", group.Key.remark);
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("date");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("orderdate", group.Key.orderdate.ToString());
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("duedate", group.Key.duedate.ToString());
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("jobdescription", group.Key.U_JobNumber);                 
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("salesperson", group.Key.U_SalesPerson);
                    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("jobtype", group.Key.U_JobType);
                    foreach (DataRow row in group)
                    {
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Components");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("itemno", row.Field<string>("itemno"));
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    var sql2 = "update IS_XML_generated='Y' from OWOR where DocNum=group.Key.DocNum";
                    clsDB.Execute(sql2);
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                }
                var xml = stringwriter.ToString();
                XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
                docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
                docSave.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\DEMO PSL\DOXMLFILE", "Filename" + count.ToString() + ".xml"));
                count++;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I fixe the error.  The initialization of the string writer should also move.